# Compute a sum involving binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $0 < a < b$ and $p_1 >0$ and $p_2>0$ be integers. The question is to prove the following identity:

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{j=a}^b 
\left(\begin{array}{c} j \\ p_1 \end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} j \\ p_2 \end{array} \right)
=
\sum\limits_{q=0}^{p_2} (-1)^{q+1} 
\left[
\left(\begin{array}{c} a+q \\ p_1+q+1 \end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} a \\ p_2-q \end{array} \right)
-
\left(\begin{array}{c} b+1+q \\ p_1+q+1 \end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} b+1 \\ p_2-q \end{array} \right)
\right]
\end{equation}

Can this identity be generalised for $p_1,p_2$ being real?

Comment: What sense do you give to the binomial coefficients for real numbers ?

Comment: Well, the binomial coefficient can be defined for any two complex numbers as \begin{equation} \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ p \end{array} \right) = \frac{\Gamma[n+1]}{\Gamma[p+1] \Gamma[n-p+1]} \end{equation}. As such it makes sense to consider generic real or even complex values for $p1,p2$.  I am not quite sure how to rewrite the right hand side in case of $p_1,p_2$ being real.

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove a more generic statement. Define:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal S}_{p_1,p_2}^{q_1,q_2}(a,b) := \sum\limits_{j=a}^b
\left(\begin{array}{c} j+q_1\\ p_1 \end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} j+q_2\\ p_2 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}
Then we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
(1) {\mathcal S}_{p_1,p_2}^{q_1,q_2}(a,b) =
\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^2 \left(\begin{array}{c} a+q_\xi\\ p_\xi \end{array} \right)
\cdot
F_{3,2}\left[
\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1+a+q_1 & 1+a +q_2 \\ & 1+a-p_1+q_1 & 1+a-p_2+q_2 \end{array};1
\right]
- \\
\prod\limits_{\xi=1}^2 \left(\begin{array}{c} 1+b+q_\xi\\ p_\xi \end{array} \right)
\cdot
F_{3,2}\left[
\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2+b+q_1 & 2+b +q_2 \\ & 2+b-p_1+q_1 & 2+b-p_2+q_2 \end{array};1
\right]
\end{eqnarray}
If both $p_1$ and $p_2$ are positive integers the above equation reduces to:
\begin{equation}
(2) {\mathcal S}_{p_1,p_2}^{q_1,q_2}(a,b) =
\sum\limits_{l=0}^{p_2} (-1)^{l+1}
\left[
\left(\begin{array}{c} a+q_1 +l \\ p_1+l+1 \end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} a+q_2  \\ p_2-l \end{array} \right)
-
\left(\begin{array}{c} 1+b+q_1 +l \\ p_1+l+1 \end{array} \right)
\left(\begin{array}{c} 1+b+q_2  \\ p_2-l \end{array} \right)
\right]
\end{equation}

We prove equation (1).
\begin{eqnarray}
(3){\mathcal S}_{p_1,p_2}^{q_1,q_2}(a,b) &:=& \left.\frac{1}{p_1!p_2!} \frac{d^{p_1}}{d x_1^{p_1}} \frac{d^{p_2}}{d x_1^{p_2}} \left(\sum\limits_{j=a}^b x_1^{q_1+j} x_2^{q_2+j}\right)\right|_{x_1=1,x_2=1}\\
&=& 
\left.\frac{1}{p_1!p_2!} \frac{d^{p_1}}{d x_1^{p_1}} \frac{d^{p_2}}{d x_1^{p_2}}
x_1^{q_1} x_2^{q_2} \frac{(x_1 x_2)^a - (x_1 x_2)^{b+1}}{1 - x_1 x_2}\right|_{x_1=1,x_2=1} \\
&=&
\left.\frac{1}{p_1!p_2!} \frac{d^{p_1}}{d x_1^{p_1}} \frac{d^{p_2}}{d x_1^{p_2}}
\left(
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty
x_1^{a+q_1+n} x_2^{a+q_2+n} - x_1^{1+b+q_1+n} x_2^{1+b+q_2+n}
\right)\right|_{x_1=1,x_2=1}\\
&=&
\left.\left(
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{(a+q_1+n)_{(p_1)}}{p_1!}\frac{(a+q_2+n)_{(p_2)}}{p_2!}
-
\frac{(1+b+q_1+n)_{(p_1)}}{p_1!}\frac{(1+b+q_2+n)_{(p_2)}}{p_2!}
\right)\right|_{x_1=1,x_2=1}
\end{eqnarray}
Now we use the identity 
\begin{equation}
(n+a)_{(p_1)} = \frac{(1+a)^{(n)}}{(1+a-p_1)^{(n)}} a_{(p_1)}
\end{equation}
and arrive at the right-hand-side of equation (1) in a straightforward way.

Now, we prove equation (2). Let us start from the second equality in (3). We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathcal S}_{p_1,p_2}^{q_1,q_2}(a,b) =\\
\left.
\frac{(-1)^{p_1+p_2}}{p_1!p_2!} 
\frac{d^{p_1}}{d x_1^{p_1}} \frac{d^{p_2}}{d x_1^{p_2}}
\frac{(1-x_1)^{a+q_1}(1-x_2)^{a+q_2} - (1-x_1)^{b+1+q_1}(1-x_2)^{b+1+q_2}}{1 - (1-x_1)(1-x_2)}
\right|_{x_1=0,x_2=0} 
\end{eqnarray}
Now, we will compute the derivatives by using the chain rule. Note, that it is only here that 
we assume that both $p_1$ and $p_2$ are integers. The derivative over $x_2$ at $x_2=0$ reads:
\begin{equation}
(-1)^{p_2}\sum\limits_{l_2=0}^{p_2}
\left(\begin{array}{c} p_2  \\ l_2 \end{array} \right)l_2!
\frac{\left[
(1 - x_1)^{a+q_1+l_2} (a+q_2)_{(p_2-l_2)} - (1-x_1)^{b+1+q_1+l_2} (b+1+q_2)_{(p_2-l_2)}
\right]}{x_1^{l_2+1}} 
\end{equation}
Now we expand the result in a Taylor series in $x_1$. We have
\begin{equation}
(-1)^{p_2}\sum\limits_{l_2=0}^{p_2}
\left(\begin{array}{c} p_2  \\ l_2 \end{array} \right)l_2!
\sum\limits_{l_1=0} (-1)^{l_1}
\left(
\frac{(a+q_1+l_2)_{(l_1)}}{l_1!} (a+q_2)_{(p_2-l_2)} 
- 
\frac{(b+1+q_1+l_2)_{(l_1)}}{l_1!} (b+1+q_2)_{(p_2-l_2)}
\right) x_1^{l_1-l_2-1} 
\end{equation}
Obviously, the only term that contributes to the result is the one where $l_1-l_2-1=p_1$.
Extracting that term out of the sum over $l_1$ and then dividing the whole result by $(-1)^{p_1+p_2}/(p_1! p_2!)$ produces equation (2).